# .Net Core Rest API Best practise

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I was wondering what the best practise would be concerning the following API structure:

OrderItemDepartment has a one to many relationship with OrderItemSection which in turn has a one to many relationship with OrderItem.

**Dividing the api into controllers with each having CRUD actions e.g.:**

- **OrderItemDepartmentsController**

  - Get: OrderItemDepartments.
- **OrderItemSectionsController**

  - Get: OrderItemSections.
- **OrderItemsController**

  - Get: OrderItems.

**..Or having a single controller serving  the OrderItems, Departments and Sections via routing:**

- **OrderItemsController**

  - Get: OrderItems/Departments
  - Get: OrderItems/Sections
  - Get: OrderItems*

Comment: I think you should avoid god controllers. God controllers/classes etc. is never a good idea. Rather you should 'stick' to single responsibility principle and spread functionality where it belongs to. This will allow you to have very intuitiv and simple RESTful routing.

Comment: I agree with @KrzysztofLa. You want a clear separation of concerns when it comes to your API structure. Having one controller to rule them all (or God controllers) will come back to bite you later in development. Return the least amount of data possible from a very specific controller method and the user's will thank you for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's a single clear answer for this that will cover all cases, but in general it's a good idea to encapsulate responsibility an logic for each specific part of your application within it's own class.

You mention CRUD (***C***reate, **R**ead, **U**pdate, **D**elete), and that is a central point here; As the name sugests, these operations typically follow a certain pattern. If you are able t organize all of your contoller-classes in a similar way, you may be able to extract common logic from them, either into helper-classes or into interfaces that each controller can implement. This will in turn make your application more flexible and less messy if (when?) you have to expand it at a later time.

Using separate controllers in the top level of your app is also likely to make it easier to organize lower-level components. For example, you might have separate business- and / or repository-components corresponding to each controller, and yet each of these components may implement common interfaces. That way, each part of your application will consist of a separate but internally consistent "vertical slice" (e.g. controller, Business and Repository).

Now if you need to add new functionality to your application, you have a clear pattern which will be easy to understand, and speed up development: Add a Controller that implements the same common interfaces as those you already have, and do the same for new components in your business- and repository-layers, respectively.